# Python. Помогите с многопоточностью или многопроцессорностью

Tags: python, многопоточность, list, multiprocessing, threading

Проблема в том, что мои потоки не работают параллельно, а запускаются, после завершения предыдущего (ну по крайней мере на это указывает print и не изменчивая скорость с потоками и без потоков)
Я уже столько всего попробовал, но ничего не выходит, кол-во говнокода растёт, а толку от этого никакого...
Мне кажется, что всё дело в списках, которые я передаю, но я так же пробовал создавать их копии, чтобы копии срезов были у каждого потока свои и они не обращались к списку из главного потока, но это так же не помогло, скорость всё равно медленная...

```
import os
from typing import Tuple, List

from threading import Thread

from csv import reader
import time

class Data:
    WORKED_THREADS = 0
    NUMBER = 0
    COINCES_FOUND = 0
    PROCESSED_LINES = 0
    LAST_LINE_NUMBER = 0
    THREAD_LIST: List[Thread] = []
    NEW_EMAILS = []



def GetSearchedEmails(fileName: str='./email.txt') -> List[str]:
    with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return [k.strip() for k in f.read().split('\n')]
    
def GetCsvLines(fileName: str='./source.csv') -> List[List[str]]:
    print('Открытие csv-файла...')
    with open(fileName, 'r', newline='') as f:
        return [row for row in reader(f, delimiter=';')]


def EditEmails(searchedEmails: Tuple[str], emails: List[str]):
    for searchedEmail in searchedEmails:
        for _ in emails:
            if searchedEmail in emails:
                Data.COINCES_FOUND += 1
                emails.remove(searchedEmail)
    return emails


def CheckCurrentInterval(emailLines: List[List[str]], start: int, stop: int, searchedEmails: List[str], index: int):
    searchedEmails = searchedEmails.copy()
    newEmailLines = []

    for line in emailLines[start:stop].copy():
        emails = [k.strip() for k in line[index].split(',')]
        newLine = line.copy()
        newLine[index] = ', '.join(EditEmails(searchedEmails, emails))
        newEmailLines.append(newLine)
        # Data.PROCESSED_LINES += 1
        # print(Data.PROCESSED_LINES)

    # Data.WORKED_THREADS -= 1
    # Data.NEW_EMAILS += newEmailLines



if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = 11
    emailLines = GetCsvLines()[:10000]
    searchedEmails = GetSearchedEmails()
    newEmailLines = []

    threadCount = 100

    csvLen = len(emailLines)
    searchedEmailsLen = len(searchedEmails)

    interval = csvLen // threadCount

    argList = []
    
    start = 0
    stop = 0

    from multiprocessing import Process

    startT = time.time()
    while stop < csvLen:
        start = interval * Data.NUMBER
        stop = interval * Data.NUMBER + interval
        Data.NUMBER += 1
        Data.THREAD_LIST.append(Process(target=CheckCurrentInterval, args=(emailLines, start, stop, searchedEmails, index)))
        Data.THREAD_LIST[-1].start()
        
        Data.WORKED_THREADS += 1
        print(Data.WORKED_THREADS)



    while True:
        os.system('cls')

        print(
            f'Длина csv-файла: {csvLen}'
            f'\nДлина txt-файла: {searchedEmailsLen}'
            f'\nИнтервал: {interval}'
            f'\nПоследний stop-индекс: {Data.LAST_LINE_NUMBER}'
            f'\nЗапущенные потоки: {Data.WORKED_THREADS} / {threadCount}'
            f'\nОбработано строк: {Data.PROCESSED_LINES} / {csvLen}'
            f'\nСовпадений найдено: {Data.COINCES_FOUND}'
        )

        
        if Data.WORKED_THREADS <= 0 and Data.LAST_LINE_NUMBER >= csvLen:
            print('Готово!')
            break

        time.sleep(1)

        
    print(f'\nКонец: {time.time() - startT} сек.')
```

**UPD.**

Вот новый код, вроде работает получше, хз

```
import os
import time
from csv import reader, writer
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pprint import pprint
from threading import Thread
from typing import List, Tuple


class Data:
    WORKED_THREADS = 0
    NUMBER = 0
    COINCES_FOUND = 0
    PROCESSED_LINES = 0
    LAST_LINE_NUMBER = 0
    THREAD_LIST: List[Thread] = []
    NEW_EMAILS = []


def GetSearchedEmails(fileName: str = './email.txt') -> List[str]:
    with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return [k.strip() for k in f.read().split('\n')]


def GetCsvLines(fileName: str = './source.csv') -> List[List[str]]:
    print('Открытие csv-файла...')
    with open(fileName, 'r', newline='') as f:
        return [row for row in reader(f, delimiter=';')]


def EditEmails(args: Tuple[Tuple[str], List[str]] = None, searchedEmails: Tuple[str] = None, emails: List[str] = None):
    if args:
        searchedEmails = args[0]
        emails = args[1]

    for searchedEmail in searchedEmails:
        for _ in emails:
            if searchedEmail in emails:
                emails.remove(searchedEmail)
    return emails


def CheckCurrentInterval(emailLines: List[List[str]], start: int, stop: int, searchedEmails: List[str], index: int):
    searchedEmails = searchedEmails
    newEmailLines = []

    argList = []
    for line in emailLines:
        emails = [k.strip() for k in line[index].split(',')]
        argList.append((searchedEmails, emails))

    print(f'Кол-во аргументов: {len(argList)}')

    with Pool(threadCount) as pool:
        for res in pool.map(EditEmails, argList):
            newLine = line.copy()
            newLine[index] = ', '.join(res)
            newEmailLines.append(newLine)
    return newEmailLines

    # Data.WORKED_THREADS -= 1
    # Data.NEW_EMAILS += newEmailLines


if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = 11
    _emailLines = GetCsvLines()
    searchedEmails = GetSearchedEmails()
    newEmailLines = []

    print(len(_emailLines))


    additionalEmailLines = []
    emailLines = []
    for k in _emailLines:
        if k[index].strip() != '':
            emailLines.append(k)
        else:
            additionalEmailLines.append(k)

    print(len(emailLines))

    threadCount = 32

    csvLen = len(emailLines)
    searchedEmailsLen = len(searchedEmails)

    interval = csvLen // threadCount

    argList = []

    start = 0
    stop = 0
    kf = 0

    startT = time.time()

    while stop < csvLen:
        if Data.WORKED_THREADS < threadCount:

            start = interval * kf
            stop = interval * kf + interval

            kf += 1

            print(f'Пул {kf} запущен!')
            newEmailLines += CheckCurrentInterval(emailLines[start:stop], start, stop, searchedEmails, index)

    print(f'\nКонец: {time.time() - startT} сек.')

    with open('new.csv', 'w', encoding='cp1251', newline='') as f:
        writer(f, delimiter=';').writerows(newEmailLines + additionalEmailLines)
```

Comment: Мне кажется у вас все ресурсы уходят на копирование данных туда-сюда. Каждый процесс получает копию всех данных главного процесса, а потом надо ещё результаты вернуть обратно. И всё это через сериализацию. Вот если бы каждый поток обрабатывал отдельный файл, получая таким образом данные независимо от основного потока - другое дело.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте передавать в порождаемый процесс не весь массив, а уже готовый срез. И это, кстати, будет уже копия, отдельно копию делать не надо будет.

Comment: я, кстати, пробовал, думал, проблема в том, что типа срез создаётся в главном потоке и это как-то пагубно влияет...
Щас буду еще пробовать

Comment: Ну, влияет, конечно, но гонять в процесс кучу данных это ещё хуже. В идеале в процесс надо передавать минимум данных, например, название файла, а процесс пусть дальше сам всё делает.

Comment: Кстати, а что у Вас делает `for _ in emails` в `EditEmails`. Есть подозрение, что гоняете цикл лишний раз

Comment: та это чтобы удалил все совпадения в списке...
без этого, он удаляет всего одно совпадение(

Comment: Я думаю, что открывать файл в каждом потоке - тоже дорогое удовольствие, потому что в csv-файле 750к строк и поэтому я делаю это в основном потоке, а потом раскидываю срезы по процессам (уже в новом коде)

Comment: Я думаю, что дешевле будет пересобрать список. Вы итерируете спискок и на него еще `remove` натравливаете, стоимость которого тоже O(n) операций. В итоге вместо O(n) Вы получаете O(n^2)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)

т.е. мне нужно просто создать новый список и забить туда нужные значения?

Comment: Если я правильно понял схему, то будет что-то вот такое у Вас: `emails_filtered = [e for e in emails if e in searchedEmails]`